# SOHO solar observatory, comet numbers and composition

Tags: astronomy, solar-system, estimation, comets

[SOHO](http://sohowww.nascom.nasa.gov/hotshots/index.html/)

> discovered its 3,000th comet, cementing its standing as the greatest comet finder of all time. Prior to the 1995 launch of the observatory, commonly known as SOHO, only a dozen or so comets had ever even been discovered from space, while some 900 had been discovered from the ground.

[image]

[Comets](http://starchild.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/StarChild/questions/question40.html)

> are believed to have two sources. Long-period comets (those which take more than 200 years to complete an orbit around the Sun) originate from the Oort Cloud. Short-period comets (those which take less than 200 years to complete an orbit around the Sun) originate from the Kuiper Belt.

My questions are:

- Can we tell, both from prior observations, and possibly SOHO data, (although I think this may be asking a lot), from which of the above sources the majority of comets originate?
- Since the launch of the Soho satellite 20 years ago, and allowing for comets it may have not observed, does this value of 3,000 comets spotted refine our estimates of how many comets may be in the vicinity of the sun at any one time, (and perhaps more importantly), in the vicinity of Earth's orbit?
- This last question may be impossible to answer, (due to solar background effects or the  complexity of measurement) but I wonder, once we know from SOHO data that a comet is about to be either completely or partially vapourised, by the heat of the sun, can we analysise it's spectrum to determine it's composition?

Comment: You should credit the quote from the website. Just like any other academic writing it is better to be generous in citing your sources than to risk the accusation of plagiarism.

Comment: @dmckee  your point is well  taken and I will change the above post. I do give credit, I hope on all posts except above , but I  have correctly  been told I have done  have too much editing in the past (trying to get a post correct), and I am loathe to overdo it again if I write  the original post incorrectly ) but I fully accept your valid point, thank you, and I  will make sure of it in the future.

Comment: I think they have looked at the composition of comets approaching the sun (using other telescopes and spacecraft than SOHO though, I think).  We have also looked at the composition by running a projectile into the surface of a comet (I think that was called the Deep Impact mission).